# How to move items from one list to multiple others with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Here's my problem. I want a script that takes the first ten items from an `<ul>` list and moves them into list1, then takes the next ten and moves them to the second one, and the same for the third one. 
I tried to do that using `jQuery.each()` but it won't work.

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list1"></ul>
    <ul class="list2"></ul>
    <ul class="list3"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some javascript. It is a fixed working one.

```
function SortCats(ul){
var array = [];
//var lis = $("#CatNavi li");
//for (var i = 0; lis.length; i++){
//  array.push(lis[i].html());
//  lis[i].hide();
//}
var $altlis = $("#CatNavi li");

var $cat1 = $(".supercat1");
var $cat2 = $(".supercat2");
var $cat3 = $(".supercat3");

$altlis.each(function(index){
alert("Shit happens");
    if (index < 10){
        $cat1.append($(this));
        alert("Shit happens");
    }
    else if (20 >= index > 10){
        $cat2.append($(this));
    }
    else if (index > 20){
        $cat3.append($(this));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I believe `jQuery.each()` can make it work here. Can you post _how_ you used it first?

Comment: show us some code, maybe add a counter and use if()/switch() statements inside so if(i<10) do... if(i > 10 && i < 20) do... etc, or instead of using a counter you could even use a normal for() loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to move first ten items of the main list (with class `list`) to the other list with class `list1` the following ten to the list with class `list2` and so on?

I propose such solution :

```
$("ul.list li").each(function(i) {
   var iList = Math.floor(i / 10) + 1;
   $("ul.list" + iList).append($("<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>"));
})
```

Comment: That's a wise and very versile solution!

Comment: Thanks! I have just edited in order to replace `round` by `floor` (that was a mistake)...

Comment: Although that's not exactly what I need since I need to manually set what goes where.